# FLEX database will not refresh after updating database unless browser is restarted

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache-flex, refresh

**EDIT - I have updated the mxml code to only show the needed code for the program to run the update.**

I am new to Flex and have an issue I hope you all can help me out with.

I have researched this issue all over and most people say use the .refresh() method to update a datagrid after updating or adding a new record. This does not do anything.

So, my issue is this. I have a mySQL database hosted on 000webhost.com, I am connecting via PHP, I have 1 mxml file and 2 php files (I know I can use just 1 but I am learning and this was easier for me to use for troubleshooting). The issue is no matter what I change on the datagrid the update does not show on the datagrid unless I close out of IE and reopen it. I can refresh or open the page in another window and the update does not show. I have to exit entirely and restart in order for any updates or additions to show.

Here is my code. I hope someone can help.

Here is my licenseTracker.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="doSend()"
           >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.List;
        import mx.controls.Text;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.ListEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        //Create array collection to hold data for datagrid 
        [Bindable] 
        private var datalist:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
        private var objSend:Object = new Object;                                

        //call hosted data php  
        public function doSend():void {
            xmlFromDatabase.send();
        }           

        //function for updating existing records
        public function doUpdate():void {
            objSend.updateAssetId = dgAssetId.text; 
            objSend.updateProgramData = dgProgram.text;
            objSend.updateSerialData = dgSerial.text;
            objSend.updateUserData = dgUser.text;
            objSend.updateCostData = dgCost.text;
            objSend.updateStatusData = dgStatus.text;

            updateDatabase.send(objSend);

            xmlFromDatabase.send();
            doSend();
            datalist.refresh();
        }

        protected function xmlFromDatabase_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            datalist = event.result.data.row;
        }           

        private function alertUpdateClickHandler(eventObj:CloseEvent):void
        {
            if(eventObj.detail==Alert.YES)
                doUpdate();
            else
            {
                //Do Nothing
            }
        }

        private function itemClickEvent(event:ListEvent):void
        {

            //apply selected datagrid to string to textbox
            dgAssetId.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.asset_id);
            dgProgram.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.program);
            dgSerial.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.serial);
            dgUser.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.user_id);
            dgCost.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.cost);
            dgStatus.text=String(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.status_id);
        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<fx:Declarations>       

<s:HTTPService url="http://mypage.com/data.php"
                id="xmlFromDatabase" 
                showBusyCursor="true" 
                result="xmlFromDatabase_resultHandler(event)"
                method="POST" />

<s:HTTPService url="http://mypage/update.php"
               id="updateDatabase"
               showBusyCursor="true"
               method="POST"
               resultFormat="text"
               result='Alert.show("Record Successfully Updated. Record May Take A Minute To Update")'
               />

</fx:Declarations>


<s:VGroup paddingLeft="20" y="10" width="1000" horizontalAlign="center">
    <s:Label width="670" height="32" color="#FF0000" fontFamily="Georgia" fontSize="24"
             text="Software License Tracker " textAlign="center"/>

    <!--Add Data grid-->
    <mx:DataGrid id="dg" x="10" y="79" width="1000" dataProvider="{datalist}"
                 editable="false" itemClick="itemClickEvent(event)">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Asset ID" dataField="asset_id" width="60"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Program" dataField="program" width="200"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Serial" dataField="serial" width="270"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="User" dataField="user" width="125"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Cost" dataField="cost" width="50"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Status" dataField="description" width="190" />               
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>

</s:VGroup>

<!--Panel for adding new entries into datagrid-->
<s:Panel id="addFrame" x="10" y="263" width="443" height="210"
         textAlign="left" title="Add/Edit Record">

    <s:Label x="60" y="10" width="191" id="dgAssetId" />
    <s:TextInput x="60" y="30" width="191" id="dgProgram" />
    <s:TextInput x="60" y="58" width="191" id="dgSerial"/>
    <s:TextInput  x="60" y="84" width="191" id="dgUser" />
    <s:TextInput x="60" y="112" width="191" id="dgCost"/>
    <s:TextInput id="dgStatus" x="60" y="142" width="191"/>

    <s:Label x="6" y="10" text="Asset ID"/>
    <s:Label x="6" y="35" text="Program"/>
    <s:Label x="6" y="62" text="Serial"/>
    <s:Label x="6" y="89" text="User"/>
    <s:Label x="6" y="117" text="Cost"/>        
    <s:Label x="6" y="147" text="Status"/>      

    <s:Button id="changeSubmit" x="312" y="33" label="Update" click='Alert.show("Are you sure you want to update the selected record?", "Update Record", 3, this, alertUpdateClickHandler);'/>


</s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

my data.php file that requests data from the server:

```
<?php


//SQL Connection Info - update with your database, username & password

$host  = "hostsite";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db_name = "database";

$mysql_connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

//Change this query as you wish for single or multiple records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.asset_id, a.program, a.serial, u.user_id, concat(u.first_name ,' ', u.last_name) as user, a.cost, s.description, s.status_id
FROM assets a
JOIN status s ON a.status = s.status_id
JOIN users u ON a.user_id = u.user_id
order by 1
");  


//Get the number of rows
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

//Start the output of XML
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>';
echo "<data>";
echo '<num>' .$num_row. '</num>';
if (!$result) {
   die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
}    
/* get column metadata - column name -------------------------------------------------*/
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)) {
              $meta = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
            $ColumnNames[] = $meta->name;                      //place col name into array
            $i++;
        }
$specialchar = array("&",">","<");                                         //special characters
$specialcharReplace = array("&amp;","&gt;","&lt;");            //replacement
/* query & convert table data and column names to xml ---------------------------*/

$w = 0;    
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<row>";
    foreach ($line as $col_value){
        echo '<'.$ColumnNames[$w].'>';
        $col_value_strip = str_replace($specialchar, $specialcharReplace, $col_value);        
        echo $col_value_strip;
    echo '</'.$ColumnNames[$w].'>';
    if($w == ($i - 1)) { $w = 0; }
    else { $w++; }
   }
    echo "</row>";
}
if($num_row  == "1"){
     echo '<row></row>';
}
echo "</data>";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

here is my update.php

```
//SQL Connection Info - update with your database, username & password

$host  = "hostsite";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$db_name = "database";

$mysql_connection = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name);


$id = $_POST["updateAssetId"];
$program = $_POST["updateProgramData"];
$serial = $_POST["updateSerialData"];
$user = $_POST["updateUserData"];
$cost = $_POST["updateCostData"];
$status = $_POST["updateStatusData"];

$query = "UPDATE `database`.`assets` SET 
`program` = '$program',
`serial` = '$serial',
`user_id` = '$user',
`cost` = '$cost',
`status` = '$status'
WHERE `asset_id` = '$id'"; 

if ( !mysql_query($query, $mysql_connection) ){
      die('ERROR: '. mysql_error() );
}
/* echo "id: " . $id;
echo "Program: " . $program;
echo "Serial: " . $serial;
echo "User: " . $user;
echo "Cost: " . $cost;
echo "Status: " . $status; */


echo "UPDATE SUCCESSFUL, 1 Record Updated";

mysql_close(); 



?>
```

I have other php files for inserts and other functions but they should not be needed to fix this issue.

Comment: In case it needs to be stated; the refresh() method of a Collection Object--such as an Arraycollection will update a DataGrid which uses the collection as its dataProvider.  However, this has no direct ties to database updates.  If you want more help or specifics you really should consider condensing your code to the minimum to demo the problem; many on this site do not want to shift through hundreds of line of code.

Comment: I shortened up the code. I hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: In the Flex code, you are calling refresh() without actually changing anything in the dataList.

Comment: I am sending the items from the textboxes to the database then refreshing. I am calling "updateDatabase.send(objSend)" before "datalist.refresh()". Am I missing something? The database does get updated but the datagrid does not update without restarting the browser

Comment: I added a formal answer.  I suspect--just guessing here--that you're getting confused between how synchronous and asynchronous calls work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the differences be synchronous and Asynchronous code.  Take, these lines, from your code

```
        updateDatabase.send(objSend);
        xmlFromDatabase.send();
        doSend();
        datalist.refresh();
```

First it calls updateDatabase.send().  This makes a remote request on your service.
Then it calls xmlFromDatabase.send()  This also makes a remote request to your service.

Both of these are asynchronous calls.  So you the xmlFromDatabase call is triggered before the results of the updateDatabase call are returned.

Then you call dataList.refresh(); which in essence does nothing because the dataList has not been changed yet.

Then at some point, your services will return back.  There is no way to guarantee the order that the services will return values.  The update database result handler will just show an alert.  The xmlFromDatabase result handler will update the dataList.

I would guess that your xmlFromDatabase handler is being returned before the updateDatabase handler, therefore the datagrid never updates with new/updated data because it never gets new or updated data.

Move the `xmlFromDatabase.send()` call to the updateDatabase result handler, and I suspect you'll see different results.

Comment: I moved the xmlFromDatabase.send() to the updateDatabase result handler and nothing changed. Still does not refresh the data. Restarting the browser is still the only way to see the update.

Comment: Have you checked the data being returned to make sure you're getting new/different data than what is currently in the grid?

Comment: Yes. the data in the database is updating as it should but the application ignores data changes unless restarted. For example I will update using the program then query the database in SQL to verify the change. I will then press F5 to refresh the app and the change is not shown. I have to exit out of IE entirely and reopen it to see the change.

Comment: I didn't ask if the database was being updated; I asked if the updated data was being received by the Flex application. Have you used a tool such as the Flash Builder Network Monitor [Or ServiceCapture or Charles] to view the packets being sent back to the Flex application?  Have you run your code in debug mode to view the changes when you change your dataList?

Comment: I just ran service capture and when first run the program loads and calls the data.php. When I hit update the update.php is run but data.php is not called again. I then hit F5 to refresh. The program reloads but it does not call the data.php again. I can not figure out why it is refusing to call the data.php again.

Comment: Well, that is the problem.  It is not obvious to me why it isn't calling that again.  But, you have lots of code to sift through.